# Table Details - Storage info vs INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_STORAGE

Tags: google-bigquery, storage, information-schema

I am trying to get the information about the storage of tables. When I use the `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_STORAGE` I get data different from the Storage info of a table.

- [`INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_STORAGE`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B3I81.png)
- [Storage Info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Re09P.png)

Why is the information about storage different? In the storage info the "Active logical bytes" are equal to zero, but when using `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_STORAGE` this value is different of zero.